# Safer way to get window scroll position

Tags: javascript, scroll

To determine how much window has been scrolled, we have `window.scrollY` alias `window.pageYOffset`, but I feel they are not pefectly reliable, because you can simply do `window.scrollY = 23401` and this value won't be replaced even after you scroll window to a new position. Same happens to `pageYOffset` too.

So is there any other property or method we can use to detect window scroll position?

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery $(window).scrollTop()

Comment: What does jQuery use then?